# '<a>' link is not able to include in table column field?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$query="SELECT A.train_no AS AA, A.station_id AS AB, A.arrival AS AC, A.dept AS AD, B.station_id AS AE, B.arrival AS AF, B.dept AS AG FROM TIME AS A,TIME AS B WHERE A.train_no = B.train_no AND A.station_id ='$f' AND B.station_id ='$t'";

$rs=mysql_query($query);


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 

{

echo "<tr><td>".$row['AA']."</td> <td>".$row['AB']."</td> <td>" .$row['AC'] ."</td> <td>".$row['AD'] . "</td><td>".$row['AE'] . 
"</td><td>".$row['AF'] . "</td><td>" .$row['AG']. "</td><td>"<a href='Reservation.php'>Click Me</a>"<tr><td>";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your `echo` statement like this. [You forgot to close the double quotes]

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row['AA']."</td> <td>".$row['AB']."</td> <td>" .$row['AC'] ."</td> <td>".$row['AD'] . "</td><td>".$row['AE'] .
    "</td><td>".$row['AF'] . "</td><td>" .$row['AG']. "</td><td>"."<a href='Reservation.php'>Click Me</a><tr><td>";
                                                            //----^ You forgot here.
```

Comment: thank you Mr.Shankar Damodaran